# Filter an Array in an Array of Objects by values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, in each object is a nested array of integers.

```js
[
  {
    "title": "Foo",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      229,
      190
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Bar",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      199,
      17
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Baz",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      199,
      229
    ]
  }
]
```

What I would like to do is retrieve an array of objects from a given array of categoryIds -  [229,17] would retrieve the first tow items?

Tried using filter, but having difficulty getting into the category array.

```js
var selectedCategories = [229,17];

posts = posts.filter(function(c) {
  return selectedCategories.includes(c.categories);
});

// posts output: []
```

Comment: So the output will contains all the three objects, right?

Comment: why not the third object?

Answer (score 1):

You should, for each post, see if any of its associated categories has an id that exists in `selectedCategories`. A simple `for ... of` loop within the `posts.filter` callback should do the trick:

```js
var posts = [
  {
    "title": "Foo",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      229,
      190
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Bar",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      199,
      17
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Baz",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      199,
      230 // Note: I made this 230 to exclude this item
    ]
  }
];

var selectedCategories = [229,17];

posts = posts.filter(function(c) {
  for (let categoryId of c.categories) {
    if (selectedCategories.includes(categoryId)) return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});

console.log(posts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, but must check each category against each selected category (or until a match is found). You can do this with `.some()`.

```
posts = posts.filter(p =>
  p.categories.some(cat => selectedCategories.includes(cat))
);
```

```js
var posts = [
  {
    "title": "Foo",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      229,
      190
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Bar",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      199,
      17
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Baz",
    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",
    "author": 2,
    "categories": [
      199,
      229
    ]
  }
]


var selectedCategories = [229,17];

posts = posts.filter(p =>
  p.categories.some(cat => selectedCategories.includes(cat))
);

console.log(posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can create a class to re-use your filter operations.**

```js
let dataArray = [  {    "title": "Foo",    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",    "author": 2,    "categories": [      229,      190    ]  },  {    "title": "Bar",    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",    "author": 2,    "categories": [      199,      17    ]  },  {    "title": "Baz",    "date": "2018-02-08T15:55:16",    "author": 2,    "categories": [      199,      229    ]  }];


function MyFilter(array) {
  this.array = array;
  this.withKey = (key) => {
    this.key = key;
    return this;
  }
  this.withComparator = (fn) => {
    this.comparator = fn;
    return this;
  };

  this.filter = () => this.array.filter(o => this.comparator(o[this.key]));
}

let categoryIds = [229, 17];
let result = new MyFilter(dataArray).withKey('categories').withComparator((catArray) => catArray.some((c) => categoryIds.some((ic) => ic == c))).filter();

console.log(result);
```

## Resources

- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Arrow functions `() =>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)